# How to repair "The type 'CrystalReportsFile' already contains a definition for 'Parameter_name' on ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, crystal-reports, temp

I have been encountering this exception when I try to either run or rebuild a solution containing a Crystal Reports File.

The error is in a file that is located in 
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\solutionname\d8cf0228\87f37e9f\App_Web_uir10yhj.2.cs

previously the solution would run, so I know that I did not edit something in the cr file...
so what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, class in file `CrystalReportsFile.cs` contains two declarations of Parameter_name of your crystal.

Try to delete at least one, or both variables.

Or if your project is a web application, delete whole designer file and in the context menu of `CrystalReportsFile.cs` choose 'Convert to web application', this will regenerate designer file.